# SQL where in clause using column in pandas dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column of IDs. I need to run another sql query whose 'WHERE' clause is dictated by all of the IDs in the aforementioned column.

Ex:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'IDs' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

query = """ Select id, SUM(revenue) AS revenue WHERE id IN (***want df1['IDs'] here***) Group by 1"""

df2 = my_database.select_dataframe(query)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the series to string

```
str = ','.join([str(x) for x in df1['IDs'].tolist()])

str
'1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

And, then insert it into the query string -

```
qry = "Select id, SUM(revenue) AS revenue WHERE id IN (%s) Group by 1" % str

qry
'Select id, SUM(revenue) AS revenue WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) Group by 1'
```

Answer (score 3):

for this to work for me I had to surround the list items with single quotes.

```
str = ','.join(["'" + str(x) + "'" for x in df1['IDs'].tolist()])
```

Comment: Then your IDs aren't an integer column.