# creating an sql query using a DataFrame column

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Based on this qs from stackoverflow:
[SQL where in clause using column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738859/sql-where-in-clause-using-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['col1'] = [1,2,3,4,5]

str = ','.join([str(x) for x in df1['col1'].unique().tolist()])
```

However, I see the below error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I want to query all the unique items in a column into another SQL table and then append those results to my original dataframe

is there another built-in approach altogether for this pls?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
df1['new'] = df1['col1'].apply(lambda x: f(x) if x in df1['col1'].unique().tolist() else 'n/a')
```

You'll need to define f(x) to take in the unique value, run the query, and return the results you want to append.  You can also change 'n/a' to whatever you want if it is not a unique value.

```
def f(x):
    "RUN QUERY HERE"
    return result
```

Comment: thanks vm - I would still need to understand how lamda works and then how should my def f(x) look like..

if you will, could you help how I could use the query in the format

`qry = "Select id, SUM(revenue) AS revenue WHERE id IN (%s) Group by 1" % str`

apols - newb here, anmd I didn't quite follow all elements in your response (which may be the best way to do it) guess am just asking for a simpler answer...?

Comment: So are you just trying to add a new column by doing a lookup from an sql table?

Comment: No I want to make a query into an sql table.. The query statement uses all the unique elements of a column in my DF. The composition of this column will keep changing hence want to be able to put it in a variable which can be accessed via my query statement.. Just like str in the above example

Comment: Can you post what versions of python/pandas you are using?  That str = ','.join.... line works fine for me

Comment: Python is 3.4.. Pandas might be pretty recent as I updated a week ago if I remember correctly