# Inserting MySQL results into an existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I looked and couldn't find this question answered (well) online.

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with a `name` column. I'd like to query a database and get the `id` associated with each name, and store that value in the dataframe.

In this case, I'm reading CSV files (with `name`), and querying a MySQL database to get `id`. I do some data cleaning and then upload the dataframe to the MySQL database (a different table then the one I query to get `id`).

**What's the best way to go about doing this?** Here's what I came up with:

```
df["id"] = pd.Series(
    [pd.read_sql_query(
        f"SELECT id FROM table WHERE name LIKE '{name}'",
            connection)["id"][0] for name in df["name"]]
    )
```

As I understand it, this avoid modifying `df` while iterating over it.

- We iterate over the values in `df["name"]`
- The SQL query returns a DataFrame
- The `["id"][0]` pulls the value of interest (`id`) out of
  the DataFrame and stores it in a list
- This list of values is converted to a `pd.Series`
- This `pd.Series` is added to the original `df`

This works, but it doesn't really force an association between `name` and `id`, which (I think) would be more robust. (And, obviously, there's no error handling in the code snippet above.)

I tried combinations of `apply` or `map` or `iterrows` or `iteritems`, and that didn't work so well. For example:

```
for index, name in df["name"].iteritems():
    id_df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT id FROM tableWHERE name LIKE '{name}'", connection)
    temp_df[temp_df["name"] == name]["id"] = id_df["id"][0]
```

Warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738859/sql-where-in-clause-using-column-in-pandas-dataframe), I'd suggest concatenating all of your names into a huge string, then inserting this string into a single SQL query (instead of a separate query per row) to get a DataFrame that maps each name to its ID.

Try something like this (can't test now, sorry!):

```
# Build a string of comma-separated, quoted names:
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/12007686
names = '"{0}"'.format('", "'.join(df['name']))

# Get a DataFrame of names and IDs
temp = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT name, id FROM table WHERE name IN ({names})",
                         connection)

# Build a pandas Series that maps each name to its ID
# Could also use a python dict. Also, ".values" may not be needed here
name2id = pd.Series(index=temp['name'].values, 
                    data=temp['id'].values)

# Create the ID column in your DataFrame. There are other ways (join, etc.)
df['id'] = df['name'].map(name2id)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this and post results. 6x fewer SQL queries is a good start!

Comment: This worked with some minor modifications. Since some of my results are Empty Sets (SQL) or np.nan (Python float), using a pandas join on `name` worked best. I'd rather join on a numerical field but that's not always possible. Thanks much!